# Creating a custom type in content element add-on a possibility or not?

Tags: solspace-freeform, content-elements

I want to know if its possible to create a custom type in content element fieldtype addon.Presently it contains a list of types like Code,Gallery,Heading etc and I want to add another type like "freeform pro" which should give an option to select all the free forms available and user can select one.
  And in the template it should load the respective form,may I know if thats a possible thing to start working on it,if so can anyone please help me out with how should I approach this development.

Cheers
Nisar

Comment: Anyone please??

Comment: It looks like you need to create a custom fieldtype first and then add a number of specific functions ( http://www.krea.com/docs/content-elements/element-development/ee2-functions-reference ). I'm about to take a look at this now for a project.